# How to add includes in Shopware 6 search criteria

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

So I was checking out the Admin SDK App example with Shopware `v6.5.4.1`:

https://github.com/shopware/admin-extension-sdk-example-app

And wanted to take a look on how to work with the repository correctly. Inside:

`src/frontend/locations/ex-product-extension-example-data.vue`

it is shown how to load a manufacturer. The admin representation can be found on the product detail route as an additional "Example" tab.

So by clicking "Load first manufacturer", I am getting a missing privileges error. So I added the [includes parameter](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/integrations-api/general-concepts/search-criteria#includes-apialias) on line 102 just to load the id of the manufacturer:

```js
async loadManufacturer() {
    const manufacturerCriteria = new data.Classes.Criteria(1, 1);
    manufacturerCriteria.addIncludes({
        'product_manufacturer': ['id']
    });
    const manufacturers = await data.repository('product_manufacturer').search(manufacturerCriteria);

    if (manufacturers) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturers.first();
    }
}
```

However, I am still getting the missing privileges error for a bunch of different entities:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which permissions are still needed? Did you add `<read>product_manufacturer</read>` after the installation? Unless you already had that, you'll have to re-install with the new permissions or increase the version and properly update the app.

Comment: In https://github.com/shopware/admin-extension-sdk-example-app/blob/main/AdminExtensionSDKExampleApp/manifest.xml#L22-L27 all `product_manufacturer` CRUD permissions are set and activated on install. The missing permissions are "random" entites. E.g. `sales_channel_domain`, `customer`, `newsletter_recipient` ...
In sum ~55 missing permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue affecting Shopware platform...

https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/4203eaa3adc6c69ae3932e1c106fa6914011877b

...and will most likely be fixed with the upcoming minor release v6.5.4.2